# Context menu not passing argument properly

Tags: batch-file, registry

I followed [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/) post to create a right-click menu for my files. I have created a batch file which gets called along with the files being clicked as its argument. In the registry I have created and entry like this:

[image]

However, when a file contains spaces in the file path, the argument gets truncated. The batch file is works fine when the arguments are passed from command prompt.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with double quote

```
Yourbat.bat "%1"
```

Or

```
Yourbat.bat "%~1"
```

Comment: Nailed it. Many Thanks

Comment: The `"%1"` will fail in many circumstances and shouldn't be used, but `"%~1"` will always work (except for some dos executables which don't support long filenames).